# Relay Server For Multiplayer Games - UNet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, unity-game-engine

I've been struggling with this issue for weeks now, and I can't find anything that can help me. Unity's topology (the one I know of) for multiplayer networking is host-client. The host starts a game, and the client connects to the host using ip:port. The problem starts when one of the parties is behind a NAT. Oblivious to this fact, I developed a web service using php to register hosts' ip and port, and when requested by client, return one of the existing hosts(ip,port, game name, etc). You guessed right, that was a total bust, At least for NATs.

So right now all I know for sure is that my only way to prevail, is to have a relay server. But I don't know exactly how to do that.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Using Socat: `socat UDP4-RECVFROM:50000,fork UDP4-SENDTO:HOST_IP_ADDR:HOST_PORT`

in which `50000` is the port the client uses in `networkManager.networkPort`, and `networkManager.networkAddress` is obviously the IP address of my server. And I got the `HOST_IP_ADDR` and `HOST_PORT` from the php webservice that I mentioned. It didn't work.

The next thing I tried was using [this python script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EtiennePerot/misc-scripts/master/udp-relay.py) as a UDP proxy server using `./udp-relay.py 50000:HOST_IP:HOST_PORT` in which, again, I got the host ip and port from the webservice. After that I set the `Network.proxyPort` and `Network.proxyIP` in unity accordingly(my server ip and port 50000); This didn't work either.

So, am I even remotely close to what I wanna achieve?

Thanks guys

## EDIT:

I wanna use a relay server, so that it'll work 100%, and not hole-punching because it doesn't work on all routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called NAT hole-punching, or punch-through.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching

Here's some good information about how to do it:

http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/

You need an introduction server that's not behind a NAT. But it's only needed to establish communication, not to relay packets. You only need to do relaying if players are behind badly-behaved NATs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter. I know about nat hole-punching, but for now I want a method that works 100%, and then I'll implement hole-punching, if feasible, and only use the relay server as a fallback.